# this.assertNotInPreviewMode not found when running a NestJS microservice

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, nest

I have a microservice setup using NestJS. However I get the following error when running it.

```
this.assertNotInPreviewMode('listen');
             ^

TypeError: this.assertNotInPreviewMode is not a function
```

I have installed the NestJS microservices package using `npm i --save @nestjs/microservices`. Have no clue as to why that function would not exist.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error today and `npm update` helped

Comment: Solved issue after updating `@nestjs/microservices` and other nest.js packages from '9.2.1' to '9.3.9' version.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your `test` folder you will see the file `app.e2e-spec.ts` you can comment or delete the code inside the `describe` method.
This will solve your problem.